# Hadoop fs shell commands not working

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm not able to run `hadoop fs shell` commands from the CLI but, able to browse the hdfs through web UI and also other hadoop commands are working fine (for example `hadoop version`). Below is the error I'm getting. Please help.

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /
-ls: For input string: "13.1067728"
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -ls [-d] [-h] [-R] [<path> ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
hdfs dfs -ls ...
```

Try this then f above doesnt works,

```
 export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

Add these two lines in .bashrc.

Comment: Tried both the options but no luck :-(

Comment: Which machine are you using or have u intsalled hadoop yourself?

Comment: I'm using CDH and running on Linux.

`$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.7.0
Subversion git://rhel64-6-0-mk3.jenkins.cloudera.com.121.29.172.in-addr.arpa/data/1/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-rhel64-6-0/topdir/BUILD/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0/src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common -r 8e266e052e423af592871e2dfe09d54c03f6a0e8
Compiled by jenkins on Wed May 28 10:11:59 PDT 2014
From source with checksum f60207d0daa9f943f253cc8932d598c8
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar`

Comment: try this  cd /usr/lib/hadoop/bin then excute your commad

Comment: try starting and stopping hadoop services ...check all are running or not with "jps" command

Answer (score 0):

export Hadoop home according to your system in .bashrc

```
#Hadoop variables
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_11
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/kishore/BigData/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
```

and execute command on terminal

```
source ~/.bashrc
```